# Java Sql Update Statement. Dealing with a Null in quotes

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, null

I have a java program executing a SQL UPDATE to a table:

```
 String qry = "UPDATE [Artists] SET [Website] = '" + artist.getWebsite() + "' WHERE [ID] = " + artist.getID() + "'";
```

If artist.getWebsite() is null it is inserting the string 'null' because of the quotes when I want to just leave it as a SQL NULL. But I need the quotes as most of the time artist.getWebsite() returns a string.
What is the easiest way of dealing with this?

Comment: Please have a look into `PreparedStatement`s. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Use. String. Concatenation. To. Build. SQL. Statements. There are several reasons for this, not least this one:

[image]

...and nulls are one of those reasons. More: http://bobby-tables.com It's also *really* easy to get confused when doing it (your example has an extra `'` at the end, for instance).

Let's ignore `null` for a moment: What if the value you're putting in the string contains `'`? Now you have a broken SQL string.

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
   "UPDATE [Artists] SET [Website] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?"
);
ps.setString(1, artist.getWebsite());
ps.setInt(2), artist.getID());
```

Note that there are no quotes around the `?` where we're going to put the string; `PreparedStatement` handles correctly quoting and escaping the content for you.

I *think* `setString` lets you set `null`s, but I haven't done JDBC stuff in a while. For non-String columns, you'd use [`setNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-); you *may* need a branch if `setString` isn't happy to do it, e.g.:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
   "UPDATE [Artists] SET [Website] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?"
);
String web = artist.getWebsite();
if (web == null) {
    ps.setNull(1, JDBCType.NVARCHAR);
} else {
    ps.setString(1, web);
}
ps.setInt(2), artist.getID());
```

...but give `setString` a go first.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for this. Will look into PreparedStatements

Answer (score 0):

Use `..NULLIF('" + artist.getWebsite() + "', ''NULL''...` when doing and update. More about operator: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx

This would return actual NULL

```
SELECT NULLIF('NULL', 'NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDBC you should always try to use prepared statements instead of just concatenating the statement manually. In particular, using the setNull() method on the prepared statement will insert a SQL NULL into the query.

Using prepared statements also helps you protect your application from SQL injection attacks.

Please see the following link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html